# Investigate the size of $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi ix^2/p}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, legendre-symbol

I attempted to look at the size of this sum, and the hint was to use Legendre symbols to split this sum into 2 sums. But from what I have seen so far, all I manage to do is simplify the sum rather than separate it into 2 new sums, and I have barely even used the notation.

Since $p$ is a prime number, we have that half of the congruences mod $p$ will be quadratic residues, and the other half will be nonresidues (with 0 being an outlier); moreover each quadratic residue will have 2 solutions. This gives us
$$ \sum_{x=0}^{p-1}e^{2\pi ix^2/p} = 1 + \sum_{(n|p)=1}2e^{2\pi in/p}. $$
Now it looks like I haven't made much headway in arriving at the solution. Would anybody be able to show me what path to take to make it further? The hope is to come to the conclusion that the magnitude of this sum shouldn't exceed $\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: See quadratic Gauss sums [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum).

Comment: One way to investigate this would be to compute the sum numerically for lots of values of $p$. Have you done this?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I have not been in the habit of looking at the numerical values, but it is a good idea and I have done so now - I will try to do this myself in future. For this, it seems the result is what I expected based on Dietrich's comment - root p or i*root p depending on congruence mod 4.

Comment: For details on how to compute this (applying a method using only elementary linear algebra), see https://mast.queensu.ca/~murty/quadratic2.pdf .